# Redirect to another site but show the original URL in browser

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I need help with a question about URL Rewrite.
Currently the redirection rule below works correctly.

```
<rule name="test_redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^name.domain.com$" />
            <add input="{HTTPS_HOST}" pattern="^name.domain.com$" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://IP address/service" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Now what I need is that the browser's address bar still displays the original url.
(Example: "http://name.domain.com" redirects to "http://IP address/service" but the browser's address bar still displays "http://name.domain.com".)
So, I made the following configuration change:

```
<rule name="test_redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^name.domain.com$" />
            <add input="{HTTPS_HOST}" pattern="^name.domain.com$" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://IP address/service" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

But didn't it work:

- The page loaded with an error.
- The "/service" has been added to the original URL.
  Where is the error? Are there some configuration missing?
  Can anyone help me with this?
  Thanks.
- Firstly, I installed the ARR module: (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing).
- After the installation is complete, I opened it at the IIS server level, selected "Server Proxy Settings", and checked "Enable proxy".
- I changed "action type="Redirect" to "action type="Rewrite".
  The IIS version is 10.0.17763.1 on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.

Comment: Please use a privacy tab of your web browser to avoid cached redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Among the iis server variables, there is no server variable `{HTTPS_HOST}`.

Please remove this from `<conditions>` and try again.

```
<add input="{HTTPS_HOST}" pattern="^name.domain.com$" />
```